# Type mismatch error in VBA when addItem to the combo box

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error, type-mismatch

```
Private Sub cmdUpdateDropDowns_Click()

    strSQL = "Select Distinct [VIN Number] From [DataBase$] Order by [VIN Number]"
        closeRS
        OpenDB
        cmbVin.Clear

        rs.Open strSQL, cnn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic
        If rs.RecordCount > 0 Then
           Do While Not rs.EOF
              cmbVin.AddItem rs.Fields(0)
               rs.MoveNext
            Loop
        Else
            MsgBox "I was not able to find any unique Products.", vbCritical + vbOKOnly
            Exit Sub
       End If  
    End Sub
```

Comment: It might help if you add the line on which you get the error.

Comment: cmbVin.AddItem rs.Fields(0)

Comment: Above line should have the error

Answer (score 0):

Change your IF Else part with this and check if it works:

```
 If Not rs is Nothing Then
   If Not (rs.BOF and rs.EOF) Then
       Do While Not rs.EOF
          cmbVin.AddItem rs.Fields(0).Value
           rs.MoveNext
        Loop
    Else
        MsgBox "I was not able to find any unique Products.", vbCritical + vbOKOnly
        Exit Sub
   End If
 End If
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but still it returns the same error.

Comment: Im trying to add list of items to a combo box using Active X controls. Some of my values has numeric values. Im getting these values from a SQL DB. Once I enter more data in to the data base this works fine. But for less data it gives me this error

Comment: Thanks for your help Jadhav. Do you have any other suggestion

Comment: This cannot happen that it works for more data and not for less data. If that the case, please debug the code. Check the rs.Fields value at each step to identify if there are any inconsistency of data or something like that.

Comment: Yeah.This is unbelievable. When the data base have 14000 records it works properly. But once I delete more than 13979 records it gives me the error. It works OK for more than 20 records :(

Comment: Have you checked data when it is getting failed for less than 20 records. If it is failing what is the error?